# How to reduce time while uploading a file in java web application?

Tags: jsp, servlets

While uploading a tiff image in java web application its taking so much time to upload. so any idea to reduce that waiting time.
I have searched a lot but tiff image will take time for uploading but anyway we can do like that we can push that to any message queue so that uploading process will go on from that message queue with out disturbing my normal work

Comment: can you open another tab on your browser to continue your "normal work"? If it is related to the uploading TIFF, you'll probably have to wait, though.

Comment: Your question is confusing. The upload speed definitely doesn't depend on file type, but on file size. Have you really measured that it's the HTTP traffic which is taking the most time? Or perhaps it's just your server side code which is written so inefficiently that it's taking so much time to process the incoming file?

Comment: any way i can do that but when it come for other users they may do not like to do and they even dont like to wait so ...

Comment: i am not able to recognize the problem but i think its due to the file size but any way there is no problem in coding because i have done only the simple process creating a file object and writting over there

Answer (score 0):

If you think your code is okay and the file size is really big, I suggest you do the upload in another thread of course

Comment: your answer is good but but can you tell me how to upload in another thread@mlwacosmos